# Knockout.js ko.dataFor

Tags: knockout.js

I have a data-bind with input textbox

```
<input id="tColorCode" type="text" data-bind="value: ColorCode" />
```

I don't have access to the external JavaScript where the view model is setup so I don't have information I need about the object but if I click an element then in the handler I can change it's value:

```
$("#tColorCode").live("click", function () {
    //....
    ko.dataFor(this).ColorCode("#ffffff");
}
```

But I need to do that outside of the click handler and so I try with the element's name but it does not work:

```
var c = $("#tColorCode");
console.log(c); //OK
ko.dataFor(c).ColorCode("#ffffff"); //TypeError: ko.dataFor(...) is undefined
```

Can this be done another way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass specific HTML element to method `dataFor`, however, variable `c` is jQuery selector, not an element.To get specific element from a selector you can simply get the first item of a selector:

```
var c = $("#tColorCode");
ko.dataFor(c[0]).ColorCode("#ffffff");  // use c[0] instead of c
```

The difference from the event handler case, is that in event hander `this` represents a specific element, not a selector, so it was working correctly.